# How to interpret Arima(0,0,0)

Tags: r, regression, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have an `auto.arima` model output with `ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean` does this indicate that the model did not fit well? Is it the case that the extra regressors have eclipsed the effect of the time and difference components? If it is valid, I do not know how to interpret the results to communicate to others why the zeroes are okay.

```
Series: y 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
      dowSunday  dowMonday  dowTuesday  dowWednesday  dowThursday  dowFriday  dowSaturday  daypartM  daypartA
         0.1427     0.1425      0.0912        0.0312       0.0136     0.1195       0.0841    0.1051    0.1275
s.e.     0.1399     0.2124      0.2120        0.1528       0.2013     0.2357       0.2375    0.1285    0.0451
      daypartE  daypartLN  inv_last24  regionSouth  regionNorth Central
        0.1697     0.0334      0.0240      -0.0234               -0.100
s.e.    0.0968     0.0736      0.1085       0.0464                0.049

sigma^2 estimated as 0.007612:  log likelihood=31.9
AIC=-33.8   AICc=206.2   BIC=-20.44

Training set error measures:
                        ME       RMSE        MAE  MPE MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set -6.321953e-17 0.04112732 0.03184536 -Inf  Inf 0.3702166 0.2447627
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An **ARIMA(0,0,0)** model with zero mean is white noise, so it means that the errors are uncorrelated across time.

This doesn't imply anything about the *size* of the errors, so no in general it is not an indication of good or bad fit.

In your case, you'll note that your $\sigma^2$  is `0.007612` and that ME is `-6.321953e-17.` These are very very small numbers, so yes, the model "fits" well.

However, the reason why they are very small is because you are fitting **15 parameters (14 coefficients + 1 error variance)** to only **18 points**.

You are likely overfitting the data to an extreme degree, and you will likely not be able to forecast out of sample very well.

Comment: Anytime you see a number on the order of e-15 or smaller, alarm bells should go off because that's [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for double precision floating point. (Machine epsilon is the smallest positive number that when added to 1, is different from 1. It captures the notion of rounding error.) Numbers that small might *mechanically* be zero, and they're not exactly zero because of floating point rounding error.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading up on over-fitting with time-series. Is the consensus to cross-validate by removing part of the sample? My current samples are fairly small already. Perhaps this type of analysis is just not possible with my data?

Comment: @PierreLafortune FYI, forecasting the stock market in the short-run with simple time series tools is almost certainly *not* going to work well. If it did, any Joe Schmo who could run a regression would get rich in the stock market. Does it make any sense at all that average returns would be different on different days of the week? If they were different, wouldn't that be incredibly simple for hedge funds or traders to exploit?
What forecastability in the stock market you do see tends to be either: (1) extremely small (2) difficult to exploit or (3) requires special information.

Answer (score 12):

Your model fit, well. **ARIMA(0,0,0)** can often appear in time series.

An Autoregressive

Let us have a look at how an **ARMA(p,q) (Autoregressive-Moving-Average)** modell is structured.

$x_t = c + \epsilon_t + \sum\limits_{i}^p * \phi_i *x_t-_1  + \sum\limits_{i}^q\epsilon_t-_1 $

An **ARMA(p,0)** modell is the same as an **AR(q) modell (Autoregressive modell of order p)**. It can be represented using the following representation.

$x_t = c + \epsilon_t + \sum\limits_{i}^p * \phi_i *x_t-_1  + \epsilon_t $

An **ARMA(0,q)** modell is the same as an **MA(q) modell (Moving-Average modell of order q)**. It can be represented using the following representation.

$x_t = \mu  + \epsilon_t  + \sum\limits_{i}^q\epsilon_t-_1 $

Hence an **ARMA(0,0)** modell is the same as an **AR(0) (Autoregressive model of order 0)** model or an **MA(0) Moving average modell of order 0** modell. An ARMA(0,0) modell is shown in the next equtation.

$x_t = c + \epsilon_t$

So the **ARMA(0,0)** model is made up of two parts:

1. A Constant
2. An error term

This means **ARMA(0,0)**, but now have a closer look what **ARIMA(0,0,0)** means.

The ***I*** in **ARIMA** stands for integration. You have to integrate the time series ***I*** before applying the ARMA modell. So in our case you have to integrate it ***0*** times.

An example for an **ARIMA(0,0,0)** modell is a time series only containing a constant and white noise, so for example a time series in which all values are the same is **ARIMA(0,0,0)**

**Here is some explanatory code in R:**

Generate two processes `FirstARIMA` is a time series which consists only of a constant. `SecondARIMA` is a process which consists of a constant and a normally distributed error term (gaussian noise).

```
library(forecast)

ARIMA000 <- rep(10,10)
FirstARIMA <- ts(ARIMA000)
noise <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
SecondARIMA <- ts(ARIMA000 + noise)

auto.arima(FirstARIMA)
```

Shows you that the first process is an **ARIMA(0,0,0)** process.

```
Series: FirstARIMA 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
intercept  
       10  

sigma^2 estimated as 0:  log likelihood=Inf
AIC=-Inf   AICc=-Inf   BIC=-Inf

auto.arima(SecondARIMA)
```

Shows you that the second process is also an **ARIMA(0,0,0)** process.

```
Series: SecondARIMA 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
        10.1683
s.e.     0.2434

sigma^2 estimated as 0.6581:  log likelihood=-11.57
AIC=27.14   AICc=28.86   BIC=27.75
```

I am plotting the two time series.

```
plot.ts(FirstARIMA)
```

[image]
    plot.ts(SecondARIMA)

[image]

Comment: Can you please check your formulas? Some TeX problems, I think